# Create a common outlet variable in superclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to define an outlet in the parent class that child classes can override?

For example, I have the following views:

```
@interface ParentView
@view

@interface FirstChildView : ParentView
@view

@interface SecondChildView : ParentView
@view
```

and the following controllers:

```
@interface ParentController
// ???
@end

@interface FirstChildController : ParentController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FirstChildView *myView;
@end

@interface SecondChildController : ParentController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet SecondChildView *myView;
@end
```

Is it possible to define an outlet in the ParentController that acts as a "parent" outlet for both myViews under FirstChildController and SecondChildController?

Comment: Try it. Also the code `IBOutlet(SecondChildView) id *myView` does not make sense, perhaps it should be: `IBOutlet SecondChildView *myView`.

Comment: When I tried it out last time, the myView in parent controller appears to refer to its own variable rather than the myView in child class.

Comment: Do FirstChildView and SecondChildView inherit from a common parent class?

Answer (score 0):

But why are you doing this... you can do it like below.

```
@interface ParentController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ParentView *myView;

@end

@interface FirstChildController : ParentController

//Assign it from your code/outlet for First Child view.
//Like self.myView = <FirstChildView>
@end

@interface SecondChildController : ParentController

//Assign it from your code/outlet for Second Child view.
//Like self.myView = <SecondChildView>

@end
```

and you can use subclass properties by typecasting.

Comment: In case FirstChildView and SecondChildView do not inherit from the same parent, it should be `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet id myView;` and typecast or access properties by using accessor methods.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for responding to my question. The following is what I ended up going with:

```
@interface ParentController
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *myView;
@end


@interface FirstChildController : ParentController

- (UIView *) myView
{
    return self.myFirstChildView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FirstChildView *myFirstChildView;
@end


@interface SecondChildController : ParentController

- (UIView *) myView
{
    return self.mySecondChildView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet SecondChildView *mySecondChildView;
@end
```

Therefore, if I have a scene using FirstChildController, the 'self.myView' in ParentController will refer to 'myFirstChildView'.